# What are the dangers of using R attributes?

Tags: r

Adding used-defined attributes to R objects makes it easy to carry around some additional information glued together with the object of interest. The problem is that it slightly changes how R sees the objects, e.g. a numeric vector with additional attribute still is `numeric` but is not a `vector` anymore:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
class(x)
## [1] "numeric"
is.numeric(x)
## [1] TRUE
is.vector(x)
## [1] TRUE
mode(x)
## [1] "numeric"
typeof(x)
## [1] "double"
attr(x, "foo") <- "this is my attribute"
class(x)
## [1] "numeric"
is.numeric(x)
## [1] TRUE
is.vector(x)
## [1] FALSE  # <-- here!
mode(x)
## [1] "numeric"
typeof(x)
## [1] "double"
```

Can this lead to any potential problems? What I'm thinking about is adding some attributes to common R objects and then passing them to other methods. What is the risk of something breaking just because of the fact alone that I added additional attributes to standard R objects (e.g. vector, matrix, data.frame etc.)?

*Notice* that I'm not asking about creating my own classes. For the sake of simplicity we can also assume that there won't be any conflicts in the names of the attributes (e.g. using `dims` attribute). Let's also assume that it is not a problem if some method at some point will drop my attribute, it is an acceptable risk.

Comment: From `?is.vector`, "is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise."  Notice that `is.atomic(x)` returns `TRUE` still.  The biggest concern I would have about objects to which I have added attributes is that some functions will strip those attributes, and it isn't always predictable when the attributes will be stripped.

Comment: @Benjamin this is exactly what I'm asking about :) I'm asking to make it more precise what are the "some" and "sometimes" cases and how bad they may potentially be. Loosing the attribute is of less concern, I'm rather asking if it can *brake* anything?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your intended use case?  Will you attach attributes to all sorts of different types of objects?  Under what circumstances will you do so?  How will you use them?  As it stands this question risks being closed for being "too broad".

Comment: @BrodieG I guess I already mentioned all the things: (1) use them to carry information to read later; (2) attach them to standard R objects (vector, matrix, data.frame etc.), (3) under any circumstances - I want make it general; (4) I want to save some information (e.g. random seed used) and read it later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my (somewhat limited) experience, *adding* new attributes to an object hasn't ever broken anything. The only likely scenario I can think of where it would break something would be if a function required that an object have a specific set of attributes and nothing else.  I can't think of a time when I've encountered that though.  Most functions, especially in S3 methods, will just ignore attributes they don't need.

You're more likely to see problems arise if you *remove* attributes.

The reason you won't see a lot of problems stemming from additional attributes is that methods are dispatched on the `class` of an object.  As long as the class doesn't change, methods will be dispatched in much the same way. However, this doesn't mean that existing methods will know what to do with your new attributes.  Take the following example--after adding a `new_attr` attribute to both `x` and `y`, and then adding them, the result adopts the attribute of `x`.  What happened to the attribute of `y`? The default `+` function doesn't know what to do with conflicting attributes of the same name, so it just takes the first one (more details at [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Copying-of-attributes), thanks Brodie).

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 10:1

attr(x, "new_attr") <- "yippy"
attr(y, "new_attr") <- "ki yay"

x + y

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(,"new_attr")
[1] "yippy"
```

In a different example, if we give `x` and `y` attributes with different names, `x + y` produces an object that preserves both attributes.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 10:1

attr(x, "new_attr") <- "yippy"
attr(y, "another_attr") <- "ki yay"

x + y
 [1] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
attr(,"another_attr")
[1] "ki yay"
attr(,"new_attr")
[1] "yippy"
```

On the other hand, `mean(x)` doesn't even try to preserve the attributes.  I don't know of a good way to predict which functions will and won't preserve attributes.  There's probably some reliable mnemonic you could use in base R (aggregation vs. vectorized, perhaps?), but I think there's a separate principle that ought to be considered.

**If preservation of your new attributes is important, you should define a new class that preserves the inheritance of the old class**

With a new class, you can write methods that extend the generics and handle the attributes in whichever way you want. Whether or not you should define a new class and write its methods is very much dependent on how valuable any new attributes you add are to the future work you will be doing.

So in general, adding new attributes is very unlikely to break anything in R. But without adding a new class and methods to handle the new attributes, I would be very cautious about interpreting the meaning of those attributes after they've been passed through other functions.

Comment: Also, canonical reference for what happens to attributes: [R-lang definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Copying-of-attributes)